# Pacemaker - Corosync - HA - Simple Custom Resource Testing - Status flapping - Started - Failed - Stopped - Started

Tags: scripting, pacemaker, high-availability, corosync

I am testing using the OCF:Heartbeat:Dummy script and I want to make a very basic setup just to know it works and build on that.

The only information I can find was this web blog here. 
https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Corosync_Pacemaker_-_Execute_a_script_on_failover.html

It has some typos but basically worked for me.

The script currently just contains the following :

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/failover.sh && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/failover.sh

#!/bin/sh

touch /tmp/testfailover.sh
```

Here is my setup :

```
cp /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/Dummy /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/FailOverScript

sudo nano /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/FailOverScript

dummy_start() {
    dummy_monitor
    /usr/local/bin/failover.sh
    if [ $? =  $OCF_SUCCESS ]; then
    return $OCF_SUCCESS
    fi
    touch ${OCF_RESKEY_state}
}

sed -i 's/Dummy/FailOverScript/g' /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/FailOverScript



sed -i 's/dummy/FailOverScript/g' /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/FailOverScript

pcs resource create FailOverScript ocf:heartbeat:FailOverScript op monitor interval="30"
```

The only testing I can really do :

```
[root@node2 ~]# /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/FailOverScript start ; echo $?
DEBUG: default start : 0
0
```

ocf-tester doesn't seem to exist in the latest HA Software Suite, not really sure how to manually install it, but the script "half works".

**The script doesn't need monitoring, its supposed to be very basic, but it seems to be flapping and giving me the following error code. Any idea's what to do?**

```
FailOverScript (ocf::heartbeat:FailOverScript):        Started
node2

Failed Actions:
* FailOverScript_monitor_30000 on node2 'not running' (7): call=
24423, status=complete, exitreason='none',
    last-rc-change='Tue Aug 16 15:53:50 2016', queued=0ms, exec=
9ms
```

**Example of what I want to do:**

Cluster start

Script runs "start.sh"

Cluster fails over to node2.

On node1 script runs "fail.sh"

On node2 script runs "start.sh"

and vis versa if it fails the other direction.

Note: The script does work, I get /tmp/testfailover.sh. I even tried putting another script under dummy_stop to remove the file and that worked, but it just keeps flapping along removing/adding/removing/adding file and starting/failing/stoping/starting etc etc.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I started just using ClusterMon and modifying the already existing/working scripts...

Comment: you should copy the script file in both the nodes

Comment: @abhi I experience the same issue, it keeps looping on the script on 1 node like OP experienced, I already copied the script file and resource file to both node, still doesn't fix it. Have you already found the solution FreeSoftwareServers?

Answer (score 1):

I realized the problem, there's a typo on [that guide](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Corosync_Pacemaker_-_Execute_a_script_on_failover.html). Your command shouldn't be between `dummy_monitor` and `if [ $? =  $OCF_SUCCESS ]; then`. That's because the `$?` take the returned result of `dummy_monitor` command. It should be:

```
dummy_start() {
    dummy_monitor
    if [ $? =  $OCF_SUCCESS ]; then
    /usr/local/bin/failover.sh
    return $OCF_SUCCESS
    fi
    touch ${OCF_RESKEY_state}
}
```

**Edit after some testing:**

The format above only getting rid of the error, but doesn't actually run the script on failover, if you want to actually run the script on failover, use:

```
dummy_start() {
    dummy_monitor
    if [ $? =  $OCF_SUCCESS ]; then
    return $OCF_SUCCESS
    fi
    /usr/local/bin/failover.sh
    touch ${OCF_RESKEY_state}
}
```

Comment: Nice to see an answer soo long after the fact, glad you got it working. I obviously don't have a test environment setup anymore but thanks for feedback!